# Decryption in Java for String Encrypted in C# using AES

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, aes

I am trying to write a code equivalent of following c# code to decrypt a string in Java.

```cs
public string Decrypt(string cipherText) 
{ 
     if (!IsBase64String(cipherText)) 
         throw new Exception("The cipherText input parameter is not base64  encoded"); 
     string text; 
     var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, SALT); 
     var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged(); 
     aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8); 
     aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8); 
     var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);  var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText); 
     using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher)) 
     { 
         using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor,  CryptoStreamMode.Read)) 
         { 
             using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) 
             {
                 // Internal 
                 text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); 
             } 
         } 
     } 
     return text; 
 }
```

Here is what I tried:

```java
final String password = "password";
byte[] salt = []; //salt provided here

String string = "something";
System.out.println(string.length());
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);

SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
System.out.println(data.length);
// skip first 4 bytes (the length of IV) and get IV byte array
byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 16, 32);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
// skip IV length (4 bytes) and IV (16 bytes)
cipher.update(data, 32, data.length - 32);
String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(plaintext);
```

Getting the following Exception:
**javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.**

Not sure where I went wrong

Comment: A good start is to debug the (internal) values, e.g. compare the derived key after "Rfc2898DeriveBytes" and "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1". Second: you should know that it is very helpful for others that try to help you when you present a full running, minimal example providing (sample) password, salt and ciphertext.

Comment: The key derivation works a little bit different in Java than in C#. In Java, the sum of the lengths of key and IV, i.e. 384 (= 256 + 128) must be specified as length (4th parameter) in `PBEKeySpec`. Thus `tmp.getEncoded()` returns 48 bytes, where the first 32 bytes are the key, and the following 16 bytes are the IV.

Comment: Furthermore, `data` contains _only_ the ciphertext, thus the decryption is simply possible with `doFinal(data)`, i.e. the `update()`-call must be removed, as well as the separation of the IV from `data`.